# Class scrbook can't get \RedeclareSectionCommands[... to not skip after chapter

Tags: koma-script, sections-paragraphs, scrbook

helping my wife with her master's thesis. Her faculty wants no more skip after headings than between normal lines and headings can be bold but not larger than 12pt. I am using `Redeclaresectioncommands`.

```
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[ beforeskip=-.2\baselineskip,
afterskip=0em ]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[ beforeskip=.2\baselineskip,
afterskip=-1em]{paragraph,subparagraph}
```

I have tried many different parameters, none of them seem to influence the skip after the chapter heading. Also, the heading font size looks a bit like it is slightly larger than the rest.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Welcome! You should show us a complete, compilable code to copy and to play with ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `afterskip=0pt` or a negative value of `afterskip` there will be no line break after a section like heading. There will be a horizontal skip instead the vertical skip. So you have to use at least `afterskip=1sp` for `section`, `subsection` and `subsubsection`.

The sectioning commands use `\par` that have a glue. Because twosided KOMA-Script documents use `\flushbottom` the vertical space around section headings can be stretched a bit. The same happens between normal paragraphs. Note that `\flushbottom` ensures that the last line is always at the lower edge of
the text body. But you can change this behaviour if you use `\raggedbottom`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=-.2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp minus 1sp,
  font={}
]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\large
]{chapter,section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  beforeskip=.2\baselineskip,
  afterskip=-1em
]{paragraph,subparagraph}

\raggedbottom

\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\blindtext
\section{A section}
\blindtext
\subsection{A subsection}
\blindtext

\vspace*{.2\baselineskip}
\noindent\textbf{Test of normal bold text with same vertical space}

\noindent\blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the chapter and section headings should have the same size as normal text, remove `\RedeclareSectionCommands[font=\large]{chapter,section}` from the example.

Comment: Brilliant. I wrote my own theses in LaTeX a while back but I never really understood all these glue things. Personally, I think it looks less nice now but that's the way the University wants it. My wife says thank you. She wants to print today. :-)